# Interpretation of the resolvent of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, stopping-times, semigroup-of-operators

$(P_t)_{t\geq 0}$ denotes the semigroup of Brownian motion, i.e.
$$P_tu(x) = E^x[u(B_t)]$$
where $u$ is a bounded and measurable function. The following operator is called the $\alpha$-potential.
$$U_{\alpha}u(x) = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}P_tu(x)\,dt$$
Here $\alpha > 0$. What I am trying to understand is what the $\alpha$-potential of the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{C}(x)$ means in a probabilistic sense. Here $C$ is some Borel measurable set. By the definition above,
\begin{align}
U_{\alpha}\mathbb{1}_{C}(x) &= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}P_tu(x)\,dt \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t} E^x[\mathbb{1}_{C}(B_t)]\,dt \\
&= E^x\left[\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t} \mathbb{1}_{C}(B_t)\,dt \right]
\end{align}
By the last expression, I first thought $U_{\alpha}\mathbb{1}_{C}(x)$ is the Laplace transform (i.e. moment generating function) of the time Brownian motion spends in $C$. But that is not true because the time BM spends in $C$ is
$$\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{C}(B_t)\,dt$$
and the Laplace transform of this random variable would be
$$E^x\left[e^{-\alpha \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{1}_{C}(B_t)\,dt} \right]$$
Defining the hitting time
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0: B_t \in C\}$$
I can write $\{B_t \in C\} \subset \{\tau \leq t\}$. But that does not lead to some insightful interpretation of the $\alpha$-potential.

A related question is what $\lim_{\alpha \to 0}U_{\alpha}\mathbb{1}_{C}$ is. I guess by monotone convergence the limit is the average time BM spends in $C$. This interpretation is correct, right?

Comment: $\alpha \mapsto U_{\alpha} 1_C(x)$ is the Laplace transform of $t \mapsto \mathbb{P}^x(B_t \in C)$ ... I don't think that there is more about it. And yes, you are right about the limit $\alpha \to 0$ (you can apply monotone convergence theorem).

Comment: @saz Thank you $ $.